# Is it possible to run two HostBuilder's from the same ASP.NET Core service at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a proxy service to wrap an older WCF service and I have it working in different modes. One that's just local and another that connects to Azure Relay.

Currently, I publish it to a folder and run it as a Windows service, but so far I can only choose 1 of the 2 modes, and **I'd like to use BOTH at the same time**. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to create two services or something?

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                switch (2) // I manually switch this for testing
                {
                    case 1: // METHOD (1) - No Azure Relay, no auth
                        webBuilder
                            .UseStartup<Startup>();
                        break;

                    case 2: // Method (2) - Azure relay WITH AUTH
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseAzureRelay(options =>
                            {
                                // Relay with no authentication
                                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("Endpoint=sb://<MYRELAY>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SASPolicy;SharedAccessKey=<MYKEY>;EntityPath=hybridconnectionauth");
                            });
                        break;
                }
            })
            .UseWindowsService();
}
```

The main reason is I can't figure out how to get the interactive Swagger web piece (for testing) working through the Azure Relay, so I need to go to `http://localhost:5000/swagger` where the service is running.

Comment: when you mean to use both at the same time, you need to clarify about the runtime argument (either from the request or whatever sources) to pick a mode. Otherwise it makes no sense. If the runtime arguments are specified, try to see if this `UseAzureRelay` could be configured as a middleware (in `Startup`) instead? Running 2 web hosts at the same time looks like just separating them into 2 web applications. But if you can configure `UseAzureRelay` as a middleware, you can use `UseWhen` or `MapWhen` to dynamically shape the pipeline based on some runtime input arguments.

Comment: @KingKing I'm new to all of this, so I could be saying it wrong. Case 2 means that whenever anyone access my API uri, it says "token required" or something, so they can't see the Swagger documentation. This is good because the API isn't just anonymous/public. They need to add the token to an `HTTP header` to authenticate...so the documentation is hidden without the header. So I'm trying to figure out how to display the Swagger documentation at the URL and also keep the API secure.